# Are array views possible?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to know if it's possible to mimic the constrained boundaries behaviour of an [`ArrayBufferView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBufferView) over an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays/ArrayBuffer) in a cross-browser compatible way (down to say IE8).

Consider a Javascript array structure like this:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I would like to obtain an array view `b` of a subset of `a`. Such as when an index of `b` is mutated, so is an index in `a`.

Usage example:

```
var b = ViewOf(a, 3, 6); // Make a view of a, from index 3 to 6
console.log(b);          // [3, 4, 5, 6]
b[0] = 42;
console.log(a);          // [0, 1, 2, 42, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Generally, no, this is not possible. You could possibly manage some kind of hack using getters and setters with `Object.defineProperty`, but it would be *very* gross, since you'd need to define a getter and setter for *every single index*. There may be a way to do this in the ECMAScript 6 draft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible by default. you can mimic it with a custom function.

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

ViewOf = function(a, startIdxx, endIdxx){
  return {
    startIdx: startIdxx,
    endIdx: endIdxx,
    set: function(index, value){
      a[index+this.startIdx] = value;
    },
    get: function(index){
      return a[index+this.startIdx];
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use the above function like below

```
b = ViewOf(a, 3, 6);
b.set(0, 42);
console.log(a);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YewC4/4/

Answer (score 1):

i don't know about IE8, since it's Object.defineProperty is janky, but this seems to do what you ask, even if what you ask isn't the best idea ever for reasons pointed out in other comments:

```
var a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

function ViewOf(orig, from, to){
   var sub=orig.slice(from, to);
   for(var i=0, mx=sub.length;i<mx;i++){(function(i){  var it=sub[i];
     Object.defineProperty(sub, i, { get: function(){ return  it;}, set: function(v){ return it=orig[i+from]=v; }   });
   }(i));}
  return sub;
}

var b = ViewOf(a, 3, 6); // Make a view of a, from index 3 to 6
console.log(b);          // [3, 4, 5, 6]
b[0] = 42;
console.log(a);  //shows: [0, 1, 2, 42, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill.

This polyfill lib has [typedarray.js](https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js) which contains polyfills for ArrayBuffer and ArrayBufferView.

I do not know this lib. Only a quick googleing..